# do not working controllerAs in the component

Tags: angularjs, components, controlleras

I made some modifications to the way the component was created.

The code looks like:

1. Question is why I should define var navbar = this; pose class ComponentCtrl If I have defined controllerAs : 'navbar' ?
2. Second question is so, if I have in this way I have written the controller, always I should define variables pose class ComponentCtrl to have variable global??

   ```
   (function () {

    var navbar = this;

   class ComponentCtrl {
   constructor() { };


   $onInit() { 
     navbar.toggle = false;
   };


   activeMenu(name, $event) {
     console.log(name, navbar.toggle);

     if (navbar.toggle === true && navbar.name == name) {
       navbar.toggle = !navbar.toggle;
     }
     else if (navbar.toggle === false) {
       navbar.toggle = !navbar.toggle;
     }
     navbar.name = name;
   };
   };

   var MyComponent = {
   bindings: {
     user: '<'
   },
   controller: ComponentCtrl,
   controllerAs: 'navbar',
   templateUrl: '/navbar/index.html'
   };

   angular.module('app.navbar').component('navbar', MyComponent);
   })();
   ```

Comment: `this` at the top outside the controller function is `window`

Comment: I dont understand can you expand it ? If I use class, inside she I can't use navbar as this? I should use this. ? How can I make variable global? in this way?

Comment: `this` inside your class is different than `this` outside it

Comment: can u expand it? why is that?

Comment: Because that's how javascript scope works

Comment: The code is  overloading the identifier `navbar` by using it both as the name of a component and as the name of a scope property with `controllerAs`. To avoid problems, make the identifiers different for the two use cases.

Comment: you mean about use different name inside controller and another in controllerAs yes?